# how to store xtabs output in a csv format file?

Tags: r, csv

I have some data as a matrix and I reshaped it to a new format using "xtabs" but I don't know how to save it as a cvs format output.

Comment: Sorry, but I may have failed to understand your question. Would you mind editing it and explaining it further? Maybe give us a sample of your code or a similar reproducible example.

Comment: AMS <- read.csv("~\matrix.csv",header=TRUE)
xtabs(value~lat+lon+month, data=AMS, exclude="")

Comment: Sorry, we don't have "mat.csv"... Reproducible means *we* can reproduce it.

Comment: Help us help you! You can improve your chances of getting the answer you're looking for by following these guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can write nearly any R object as csv using the `write.csv` function in such manner:

```
write.csv(xtable(...), "filename.csv")
```

Longer answer: the whole `write.table` function family is highly customizable, but usually one of these two should be enough for most people if you're exporting to CSV:

1. Use `write.csv` to use `.` as a decimal separator and `,` as column separator;
2. Use `write.csv2` to use `,` as a decimal separator and `;` as column separator;

More info at http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html

Comment: I know about write.csv but the problem is that I don't know where or how "xtabs" function save the matrix which it creates and how I can recall it with write.csv command.

Answer (score 0):

***Hello,  please read any of the manuals avaiable here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info  (specifically the `r intro`)***

---

As for your question:

calling the `xtabs` function on your object does not alter the object.  Instead it creates a NEW object.  If you would like to save it (or do anything with it), you need to assign it to something.

You do this with `<-`  or with `=`  (they are different, but thats not important in this context)

Use the following:

```
 newmydata <- xtabs(mydata)
 write.csv(newmydata, <etc..> )
```

Note you can also overwrite your original data:

```
 mydata <- xtabs(mydata)
 write.csv(mydata, <etc..> )
```