# Reading csv file as xtabs (two- or multi-way array) in R

Tags: r, arrays, xtabs

Storing a xtabs (two- or multi-way array) in R is straightforward. See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307613/how-to-store-xtabs-output-in-a-csv-format-file). Is there an equally easy way to read a csv file as xtabs object (array)?

As a toy example, this is a two-way array:

```
crosstbl
   Column
Row   A   B   C   D
  I  10  50  20  20
  J  20 100  40  40
  K  15  75  30  30
  L  25 125  50  50
  M  12  60  24  24
  N  20 100  40  40
```

It can be saved as a csv-file:

```
write.csv(crosstbl, 'two-way.csv')
```

And it can be read from that file:

```
new_crosstbl = read.csv('two-way.csv', row.names=1)
```

This will be, however, a data.frame.

Three-way table might look like this:

```
crosstbl3
, , Slice = CA

    Column
Row   BA  BB  BC
  AA  10  50  20
  AB  20 100  40
  AC  15  75  30
  AD  25 125  50
  AE  12  60  24
  AF  20 100  40
  AG  10  50  20
  AH  30 150  60

, , Slice = CB

    Column
Row   BA  BB  BC
  AA  40 200  80
  AB  80 400 160
  AC  60 300 120
  AD 100 500 200
  AE  48 240  96
  AF  80 400 160
  AG  40 200  80
  AH 120 600 240
```

And when saved it changes to a different format:

```
Row Column  Slice   Freq
AA  BA      CA      10
AB  BA      CA      20
AC  BA      CA      15
... ...     ...     ...
```

So how can we save and read two- and multi-way xtabs (arrays) in the same way?